# Python and Starlette - receiving a tuple from an API that's trying to return json

Tags: python, json, starlette

I'm working on a Starlette API.  I am trying to receive a response object or json but I end up with a tuple.  Any thoughts or guidance will be appreciated.

Frontend:

```
headers = {"Authorization": settings.API_KEY}
association = requests.get(
    "http://localhost:9999/get-association",
    headers=headers,
),
print("association:", type(association))
```

association: <class 'tuple'>

Backend:

```
@app.route("/get-association")
async def association(request: Request):
    if request.headers["Authorization"] != settings.API_KEY:
        return JSONResponse({"error": "unauthorized"}, status_code=401)
    # return JSONResponse(
    #     content=await get_association(), status_code=200
    # )
    association = {"association": "test data"}
    print("association:", type(association), association)
    return JSONResponse(association)
```

association: <class 'dict'> {'association': 'test data'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma after `requests.get`. This is making a tuple of `(<Response [200]>,)`.

Comment: Wow, I'll call you Hawkeye !